# What is the effective way to define Ansible configuration

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am trying to understand to how to define my configs in host_vars files.
I have individual files for each router.

```
abc_router.yaml:
---

lacp_channel:

  - { group: 101, mode: trunk, description: , vpc: , trunk_vlans: "1056", trunk_allowed_vlans: }
  - { group: 102, mode: trunk, description: , vpc: , trunk_vlans: "1056", trunk_allowed_vlans: }
  - { group: 103, mode: trunk, description: , vpc: , trunk_vlans: "1056", trunk_allowed_vlans: }
  - { group: 104, mode: trunk, description: , vpc: , trunk_vlans: "1056", trunk_allowed_vlans: }


interface_port_channel:

 - { interface: Ethernet 2/1, channel_group: 125, mode: active }
 - { interface: Ethernet 2/2, channel_group: 125, mode: active }

.....
```

Question I have is, for growing configuration, do we keep existing config or every time config is applied, we clean up and enter fresh config.?? what is the recommendation. I am not able to find this info online

I am asking this due to the way Ansible works. Ansible goes through one by one. 
Initially we start with empty file above. Then we added few lacp_channel and interface_port_channel. Now the file is growing. Lets say we have now 100 lacp_channels.  We just want to add a new interface to interface_port_channel

My ansible code first checks lacp_channel which has 100 rows. There is no change here, but ansible runs to see if it needs to apply this change.
Then it comes to interface_port_channel and applies config.
So we are wasting lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Could you share some more information on how you reference these vars? How do you loop through them?

I've managed iptables rulesets with over 1000 lines in 1 vars file. They filled up a jinja2 template I created and the only task referencing these vars was to copy the template in place on the firewalling server. It executed really fast...

If you are using a loop or with_items, maybe you can have a look and reorganize the way you use variables?

Also, if you ever want to split up configuration and assemble them to 1 config file, take a look at  https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/assemble_module.html